# Bad date format string string error

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I created an asp application with crystal report. In that dates are stored as varchar in sql, and pass that value as string from asp to crystal report. Here that string format is converted to date by using Datevalue function. But i try to execute the report it shows bad date format string error. date format stored in sql is 'dd/mm/yyyy'
How to convert the string to date value in crystal report

Comment: Why not converting the string date to date before sending it to the crystal report. Make sure you are not passing null and empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..

```
"From : " & ToText(Minimum({?date}), "dd/MM/yyyy") & 
" To :" & ToText(Maximum({?date}), "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

If the datetime is in field (not a formula) then you can format it:

Right click on the field -> Format Editor
Date and Time tab
Select date/time formatting you desire (or click customize)
If the datetime is in a formula:

```
ToText({MyDate}, "dd/MMM/yyyy")
//Displays 31/Jan/2010
```

or

```
ToText({MyDate}, "dd/MM/yyyy")
//Displays 31/01/2010
```

or

```
ToText({MyDate}, "dd/MM/yy")
//Displays 31/01/10
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

use the string conversion to date

```
CDate ("17/02/2014") or CDate(<<Database Field>>)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if not "cdate" error "bad date format for string" 

local stringvar input := {table.field};
date(val(input[1 to 4]),val(input[5 to 6]),val(input[7 to 8]))
```

I found this successful!